# VueJS / Vuetify - Possible to dynamically load a data table without having to hard-code the columns?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Good day,

In trying to learn VueJS I wanted to make a generic [Vuetify Data Table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#api) that could receive an array of objects with `n` properties, where `n` is unknown.

Every example and article I've found about using these tables hard-codes the object properties into their `headers` and `items` slots, something like this:

```
<template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
  <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
  <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
  <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
  <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
  <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
</template>
```

Which is fine if I have 1 or 2 datasets. But what if I want to load one of 100 different datasets into my data-table? Do I really need 100 different "foo-table" components with hard-coded values?

How do I handle the template interpolation that would allow me to reuse a single data-table component that could handle data like:

```
items: [{ name: 'foo', age: 100, occupation: 'retired' }, ...]
```

*and*

```
items: [{ seq: '1234', data: 'XYZ', flag: 'N', operator: 'someone',  }, ...]
```

and correctly `v-for` each `<tr>` by the item and the `<td>` by each item parameter as dictated by the `headers` (where `item[n][header[i].value]`)?

---

**What I've done so far.**

I've spent a fair amount of time on this and the best I came up with is something like the following:

```
<template slot='items' slot-scope='props'>
  <tr v-for='(item, i_index) in items' :key='i_index'>
    <td v-for='(header, h_index) in headers' :key='h_index'>
      {{ items[i_index][header.value] }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

But it doesn't work because it's producing items.length-times as many rows because I think the `items slot` is already implicitly doing a v-for inside of it, making my `<tr v-for ...>` redundant.

---

Does anyone have any better ideas on how I can accomplish a generic data-table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think the items slot is already implicitly doing a v-for inside of
>   it.

That's correct, and you only one loop for each row:

```
<template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
  <td v-for="header in headers">{{ props.item[header.value] }}</td>
</template>
```

See this adapted pen from vuetify site. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/daQbrE?&editable=true&editors=101

Comment: Wonderful! That did it. Thank you so much.